# Javascript inserting CSS into head

Tags: javascript

Using the following script I include text and insert css into my page head at run time. However, although the css in inserted it does not take affect. Why?

```
(function () {

    var styleEl = document.createElement("link");
    styleEl.type = "text/css";
    styleEl.href = "/static/css/widgets.css";
    //document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleEl);
    document.head.appendChild(styleEl);


    var foo = "Goodbye World!";
    document.write("<p class='example-widget-container'>Inside our anomymous function foo means '" + foo + '".</p>');
})();
```

Comment: Just guessing but try adding rel="stylesheet"?

Comment: Don't use `document.write`! See the warning in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#document.write%28%29). Use DOM methods instead.

Comment: @Adrian Mitev that worked thank you! Would you like to add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add `rel="stylesheet"` which is important for declaring a stylesheet `<link>` tag.

Here is the updated code with setting of the `rel` property:

```
(function () {
    var styleEl = document.createElement("link");
    styleEl.type = "text/css";
    styleEl.href = "/static/css/widgets.css";
    style.rel = "stylesheet";

    //document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleEl);
    document.head.appendChild(styleEl);


    var foo = "Goodbye World!";
    document.write("<p class='example-widget-container'>Inside our anomymous function foo means '" + foo + '".</p>');
})();
```